# catch.hpp error messages with visual studio

Tags: visual-c++, catch-unit-test

Using visual studio 2015 to compile a test code using `catch.hpp` unit test.  I need to write code to interface with serial port and will need to interface with Widnows API and need to include `windows.h`

But compiler generates complains with error messages below.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2888   'Catch::Colour::Colour(Catch::Colour::Code)': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'Catch' NMCR_Testing    c:\users\ahajmousa\google drive\cto projects\new mc receiver\software\testing\nmcr_testing\nmcr_testing\catch.hpp   7796
>   Error   C2888   'Catch::Colour::Colour(const Catch::Colour &)': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'Catch'   NMCR_Testing    c:\users\ahajmousa\google drive\cto projects\new mc ....
>   ......

code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("first Test")
{
    REQUIRE(1 == 1);
}

TEST_CASE("2nd  Test")
{
    REQUIRE(1 == 0);
}
```

Errors will go away if I do not include widnows.h
Is there a way to get catch.hpp to compile without these errors.

Comment: It is not very clear how this program could generate those error messages.  But as posted it certainly can't compile, you must move the #include for window.h *after* the #include for catch.hpp.  That takes care of the necessary NOMINMAX define.

Comment: Thanks for response, moving the header definitions after catch.hpp fixed problem.